# VueJs and Phpunit

Tags: javascript, laravel, phpunit, vue.js

I have 3 dependents . Each select get his data through VueJs and AJAX.

So, here is one on my selects:

```
<select name="federation_id" v-model="federationSelected"  class="form-control" @change="getAssociations(federationSelected)">
    <option v-for="federation in federations" v-bind:value="federation.value" selected="@{{ federationId==federation.value }}">
@{{ federation.text }}
</option>
```

And it works great!

But when I run my phpunit test, I get a constraint error on one FK because it want to execute query:

```
SQL: update `test_users` set `federation_id` = {{ federation.text }}
, `association_id` = {{ association.text }} , `avatar` = avatar.png, `updated_at` = 2016-05-18 12:43:08 where `id` = 237)
```

I understand the problem, as VueJs is not interpreted, it doesn't replace {{ association.value }} to the value, so it fails.

Is there anything I could do about it???

I mean, I don't really want to use Selenium or PhantomJS, I'm quite confortable with my tests.

Also, I could just test the api, and send a post with my value, but I'm not sure I want to do it... I like the "type" feature to enter text in an input and submit manually. It is not Javascript, but it is more than an api request.

What I would like to do is provide a default value (1) to my combos, so that it doesn't affect my tests.

My tests will not cover those 3 fields, but it is ok for me.

But still, I don't really know if it is posible, and how to do it!

Any idea???

Comment: You'll have to use something that can run the JS if you want to do an e2e test.  Otherwise you can test your endpoints with mocked values.

Comment: I'm more interested in the second option, can you please detail?

Comment: You can use Laravel's testing API to send requests to your endpoints and then evaluate the response: https://laravel.com/docs/master/testing#testing-json-apis .  I just did this in a todo list app, here is my testing file: https://github.com/jsiebach/angular-todo/blob/master/tests/TodoTest.php .  I think this is what you said you know how to do.  I just don't think you can test with typing in those fields without running JS tests with karma.  Evan has a few examples of these tests available in some of the demo apps

Comment: yep, I wish I can do better than testing just the post. Karma??? I will check it, never heard about it

Comment: oo, karma looks amazing, but it is only for Angular, no?

Comment: Check out https://vuejs.org/guide/application.html#Unit-Testing .  I think Protractor is angular-specific but Karma works for Vue.  Karma is what Evan uses is his demo applications, you can look up examples